# Multiple left joins using slick?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following slick entities:

```
class Person(personId, houseId, carId)
class House(houseId)
class Car(carId)
```

I want to select a Person and their optional house and car, my query is:

```
val query = personTable
      .filter(_.personId === personId)
      .joinLeft(houseTable)
      .on(_.houseId === _.houseId)
      .joinLeft(carTable)
      .on(_._1.carId === _.carId)
      .result
      .headOption
```

However, the return type of the query looks a little funny, I'd expect it to be a tuple(person, house, car):

```
Option[(Person, Option[House], Option[Car])]
```

But it's actually a tuple(tuple(person, house), car):

```
Option[((Person, Option[House]), Option[Car])]
```

The data that comes back does seem correct, its just in an unusual structure, maybe I'm not performing the multiple joins correctly above?

Comment: Perhaps if you try to rewrite this within a for-comprehension (look at the example in the [applicative join](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html?highlight=join#applicative-joins)), you would be able to change the format of the query to return a single tuple. Since for-comprehensions are just, nice, syntactic sugars, a `map` would probably do the job as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things look normal to me.

If you don't like the current datatype, you can `map` in your query to change it, like this e.g:

```
val query = personTable
      .filter(_.personId === personId)
      .joinLeft(houseTable)
      .on(_.houseId === _.houseId)
      .joinLeft(carTable)
      .on(_._1.carId === _.carId)
      .map{case((person, houseOpt), carOpt) => (person, houseOpt, carOpt)}
      .result
      .headOption
```